# Why should I use MetadataSourceAdapter with MOXy instead of accessing XML mapping files directly?

Tags: java, jaxb, moxy

I have a question for JAXB / MOXy experts:

Why should I extends `MetadataSourceAdapter` to associate a XML mapping file with a bean, instead of loading directly the mapping file in the JAXBContext ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**

> Why should I extends MetadataSourceAdapter to associate a XML mapping
>   file with a bean, instead of loading directly the mapping file in the
>   JAXBContext ?

You shouldn't.  If your metadata is in a mapping file then you should bring it in that way:

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
properties.put(JAXBContextFactory.ECLIPSELINK_OXM_XML_KEY, "com/example/oxm.xml);
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example", Foo.class.getClassLoader() , properties);
```

---

**When Should I Extend `MetadataSourceAdapter`?**

`MetadataSource` interface and the skeleton `MetadataSourceAdapter` implementation allow you to pass the metadata in as the Java object model corresponding to the mapping document. This object model is generated from the XML Schema for the mapping document using JAXB.  It is useful when you want to build up the metadata programmatically.  Below is an example from my blog that demonstrates how this can be useful.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/moxy-extensible-models-refresh-example.html

Comment: Thx for the answer Blaise!
I am indeed using mapping files and am loading them directly.